# get id from template php to model (MVC)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a Project using MVC, in file chocanh.php , I want to get the id when clicking the button and return the id to the file muahang.php in the model.

[Display in website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt5FG.png)          [code in chocanh.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBH2S.png)              [code in muahang.php (model/muhang.php)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBRq9.png)

Answer (score 0):

chocanh.php
`<a id="11" onclick="getId(this)">OK</a>`

```
<script>
   function getId(input) {
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/model/muhang.php",
          data: { id: input.id },
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(response) {
            if(data === true) {
              console.log("success")
            }
          }
     });
 }
</script>
```